# PHP Email Send value of checkbox Yes if checked No if Unchecked

Tags: php, html, email, checkbox

Hello I am creating a HTML + PHP email form. My form and function is working perfectly aside from my checkboxes. I have two checkboxes.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="boxfan" name="boxfan[]"/>
<label for="boxfan">A fan?</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="boxgbps" name="boxfan[]"/>
<label for="boxalbum">Bought an album?</label>
```

I want the value to be send as Yes or No, send Yes if the checked and No if unchecked.

**For example:**

A fan? Yes

Bought an album?  No

Any, suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

My actual form [is here](https://connspire.com/nycon/bestil-penryn-dual.html) It's in Danish that's why I just used a simple example.

Comment: `$yn = (isset($_POST['boxfan'][$i])) ? 'Yes' : 'No'`. Since checkboxes aren't submitted unless they ARE checked, the mere presence of the checkbox's name in _POST means it was checked.

Comment: I'm not going to put in answer until I see what you have as far as PHP goes. Seeing what you've posted for code, you're (and as you already know) doing it incorrectly. Questions like these, (and I take this from experience), always tend to open up a "can of worms". There are too many ways to go about this. So far, Marc B's comment (`+1`) is a good method, using a ternary operator.

Comment: @MarcB is right. What he's suggested is a simple ternary that says if it's set (yes only checkbox), its yes. If it doesn't (exist), it's automatically no. 'Tis the only way (other than maybe a convoluted creation of an arbitrary "no" checkbox via JS)

Comment: Thanks you guys, looks like you are right, so I'll just use a condition then. Thanks, appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to send each in a seperate email:

```
foreach($_POST['boxfan'] as $boxfan){
    if(isset($boxfan)){
        $message = "Yes";
        mail($to, $subject, $message);
    } else{
        $message = "No";
        mail($to, $subject, $message);
    }
}
```

But if you want to send both in one email:

```
$message = null;
foreach($_POST['boxfan'] as $boxfan){
    if(isset($boxfan)){
        $message .= "Yes\r\n";
    } else{
        $message .= "No\r\n";
    }
}
mail($to, $subject, $message);
```

Comment: this is interesting, I'll try this one.

Answer (score 0):

This is how Rails does it:

```
<input type="hidden" name="boxfan" value="No"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="boxgbps" name="boxfan" value="Yes"/>
```

[EDIT] but you won't be able to make it an array variable then.